# Why is the work being done by my QThread starving the main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyside

Here's my lovely thread I've written based on QThread. You'll notice it has an event queue. After 4 seconds an event fires and does some work in `doWork`. `doWork` should sleep in between all its printing and give other threads a chance to run. Suffice it to say with all the printing and sleeping `doWork` runs long enough that another thread really should get some time to execute.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class DoStuffPeriodically(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DoStuffPeriodically, self).__init__()

    def doWork(self):
        #... do work, post signal to consumer
        print "Start work"
        for i in range(0,100):
            print "work %i" % i
            QThread.msleep(10)
        print "Done work"
        return

    def run(self):
        """ Setup "pullFiles" to be called once a second"""
        self.timer= QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.doWork)
        self.timer.start(4000)
        self.exec_()
```

Here's the top-level QT widget I'm using to control my thread. Its basically just a push button that starts/stops the thread.

```
class Widg(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widg, self).__init__()
        self.thread = DoStuffPeriodically()
        self.startStopButton = QPushButton()
        hBoxLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        hBoxLayout.addWidget(self.startStopButton)
        self.startStopButton.pressed.connect(self.startStopThread)
        self.setLayout(hBoxLayout)
        self.threadRunning = False

    def startStopThread(self):
        if self.threadRunning:
            print "Stopping..."
            self.thread.exit(0)
            self.threadRunning = False
            print "Stopped"
        else:
            print "Starting..."
            self.thread.start()
            self.threadRunning = True
            print "Started"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv
    qApp = QApplication(argv)    
    widg = Widg()
    widg.show()
    qApp.exec_()
```

If I click the startStopButton, I expect to see the thread begin printing

```
Starting...
Started...
Start Work
work 0
work 1
...
work 99
Done Work
```

But what I want to do is to be able to stop the thread while its doing work. I expect something along the lines of

```
Starting...
Started...
Start Work
work 0
work 1
...
work N
Stopping...
work 99
Done Work
Stopped...
```

Instead, **the worker thread appears to be preventing the main thread from executing?** And I have to wait for the work to be done before I can click the startStopButton, giving me

```
Starting...
Started...
Start Work
work 0
work 1
...
work 99
Done Work
Stopping...
Stopped...
```

It doesn't matter how long `doWork` runs. I`ve upped it to loop 10000 times. **It doesn't appear to ever give time back to the main thread and the widget is unresponsive.** Am I doing something thats preventing real threading from actually working?

(I'm using python 2.7 and pyside 1.10.)

#### Update

If I modify `run` to do the work directly, not based on the `QTimer` the threading appears to work correctly. Ie change `run` to:

```
def run(self):
    self.doWork()
    return
```

This doesn't solve my problem, because I want to run using the event queue. I suspect therefore, that this is some kind of signals/slots problem where the `QTimer` signal is associated with the wrong thread.

**Note I'm not exeriencing that `exit` or `quit` blocks until the work is done. I'm simply experiencing the threading not work at all. Namely the main window is blocked and I can't even click the button to even initiating quiting the thread**

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `QThread` method is doing the work. The thread affinity of `QThread` is always the [thread that created](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects#64a093776750c691afdeb133a80f55e2) the QThread. Therefore, the signal tells `QThread`'s owning thread to execute `doWork`--in this case the main thread. So even though `doWork` is defined in this QThread, the work is done by the main thread. I know kind of mind twisting. To explain, let me begin by quoting the docs

> QThread object is living in another thread, namely, the one in which it was created.

so when this signal/slot connection is setup

```
 self.timer.timeout.connect(self.doWork)
```

it, by default is an [AutoConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum):

> (default) If the signal is emitted from a different thread than the receiving object, the signal is queued, behaving as Qt::QueuedConnection. Otherwise, the slot is invoked directly, behaving as Qt::DirectConnection. The type of connection is determined when the signal is emitted.

The source of the signal is my QThread, because QTimer was created in the `run` method, but the destination is the main thread. Its being queued in the main thread's event queue! The solution is to create a second worker QObject which will have the affinity of the current thread:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def doWork(self):
        #... do work, post signal to consumer
        print "Start work"
        for i in range(0,1000):
            print "work %i" % i
            QThread.msleep(100)
        print "Done work"
        return
```

Then run becomes:

```
def run(self):
    """ Setup "pullFiles" to be called once a second"""
    print "Running..."       
    self.worker = Worker(parent=None) #affinity = this thread
    self.timer= QTimer() #affinity = this thread
    print self.timer.thread()
    self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.worker.doWork)
    self.timer.start(4000)
    self.exec_()
    print "Exec_ done"
```

And this works. The source and destination of the signal is all in one thread and doesn't traverse back to the main thread. Voila!

Comment: What has a bowed string instrument have to do with it? <g>

Answer (score 0):

From [QThread::exit()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qthread.html#exit) documentation:

```
Tells the thread's event loop to exit with a return code.
```

Your `doWork` is a single event in the event loop. The event loop called your event, therefore it waits for it to finish. `exit` is yet another event, enqueued in the event loop and waiting for `doWork` to finish. The `msleep` helps the responsiveness of your GUI (gives it time to repaint and execute the button handler), but it really does not enable the `exit` event to sneak in somehow.

If you want your `doWork` to be interruptable at any time, you must change your logic. Make the timer fire more often and increment only by one. exit then can act anytime in between.

Comment: Yeah I know this, but I expect the main thread to still run while waiting for the exit. I would be ok if I blocked on the exit, but the button simply can't be pushed. I know the answer now though and will post it.

Comment: Actually btw I created this to test your answer :) Which appears correct